# Ubuntu TTY repeats Enter Key forever

Tags: login-screen, tty

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Whenever I try to access any of the TTY  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F(1-6)</kbd>, it asks me for my username. I enter my username and press <kbd>`enter`</kbd> then I am supposed to type my password. However, after pressing <kbd>`enter`</kbd> at the first time (after typing my username), it keeps hitting enter like forever. I do not even have a chance to enter the password.

So, the scenario goes as follows:

1. I enter my username
2. Press enter
3. Requests password and immediately it acts as if an <kbd>`enter`</kbd>  is pressed
4. It keeps going like this until it reaches the maximum number of login attempts.
5. All of that happens without even touching my keyboard after the first <kbd>`enter`</kbd> hitting.

So, how to solve this problem?

*Edit*: I entered recovery mode and ran package fix successfully.

Comment: Are you able to open a normal `terminal` window and successfully type commands there? Have you tried another keyboard?

Comment: @heynnema, Yes. Everything is working fine.
The keyboard is fine. I am using it on the terminal and it is working fine. The problem comes when I am on the TTY screen.

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard? Any difference if you use the ENTER key on the numeric keypad, instead of the normal ENTER key?

Comment: @heynnema, yes. Same problem!

The only way to overcome this problem was to remove my password so that I can have access with only a single ENTER press.